# how should a neural network learn clusters assuming a particular weight matrix and learning rate?

Tags: neural-network, cluster-computing, bioinformatics

let us consider a set of six points S={a(-1,1),b(-1,2),c(1,0),d(1,2),e(2,-1),f(2,2)} on a two dimensional eucledian plane.initially the six points form three clusters as {a,b},{d,f} and {c,e}.given the number of clusters to be formed as 3 , how should a neural net learn the clusters by applying the winner take all its learning strategy. assume that weight matrix w=[{0 -1 2},{2 0 1}] and learning rate =0.5

Comment: `artificial neural networks` in general are not methods for clustering, but for supervised machine learning. Are you referring to `self-organizing maps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Genesis Software free trial or JMP SAS. They have excellent documentations and the algorithms you need are implemented therein